# How to get two divs inside another div the same height without using fixed height

Tags: html, css

Hello i'm wondering if its not possible to set the right column to the same height like the left column with an image inside. Everything without fixed heights?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GWZuq/3/

[image]

my HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left_col"><img src="http://www.monstersandcritics.de/image.php?file=downloads/downloads/musik/zaschamoktanstateofmind_1/images/group1/Zascha-Moktan-State-Of-Mind_201128_248803_1_024.jpg&width=600"></div>
    <div class="right_col">some text ul etc</div>

</div>
```

my css:

```
.wrapper{
    width:80%;
}
.left_col{
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    float:left;
}
.left_col img{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.right_col{
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background-color:pink;
    height:100%; /* why is this not putting right col to 100% of the parent container?
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is due to `float: left` that make wrapper getting a height of 0 pixel

Comment: What's with all those `position:relative`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replace your CSS with the following CSS ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8fuZY/)):

```css
.wrapper {
    width:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left_col {
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:10000px;
    margin-bottom:-10000px;
}
.left_col img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.right_col {
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background-color:pink;
    padding-bottom:10000px;
    margin-bottom:-10000px;
}
```

### Alternate solution

Alternatively, you could change the HTML and CSS to use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/28Kzv/)). This solution also allows for aligning vertically:

#### HTML

```
<figure class="wrapper">
 <img src="http://www.monstersandcritics.de/image.php?file=downloads/downloads/musik/zaschamoktanstateofmind_1/images/group1/Zascha-Moktan-State-Of-Mind_201128_248803_1_024.jpg&width=600"><!-- Comment out white space
 --><figcaption>some text ul etc</figcaption>
</figure>
```

#### CSS

```css
figure.wrapper {
    width:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:pink;
}
figure.wrapper img {
    width:80%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:middle; /* top, bottom, or middle to align image vertically */
}
figure.wrapper figcaption {
    width:20%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle; /* top, bottom, or middle to align caption vertically */
}
```

***Note:** This solution uses new elements which will not work in IE8 and lower unless they are registered via JavaScript. This can be overcome by including html5shiv ([Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/), [GitHub](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv)).*

Comment: @Jurudocs, add `margin:0 auto;` to `.wrapper` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8fuZY/1/)).

Comment: Look's like hack. Isn't more gracious way exist?

Comment: @dragn, it's a hack that works. Compared to non-hacks (e.g. `display:table;` or flexbox) which don't work in as many browsers. And really, it's defined behavior, so it's not really a hack (like the star hack is).

Comment: @maco, your example breaks scrolling and text flows out of the box (making that more of a hack than my example). See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/GWZuq/19/). My code, on the other hand, extends the backgrounds of both down, if either column is taller than the other ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8fuZY/2/)).

Comment: @bfrohs, what I mean is CSS looks.  You are not wrong.  However, I think 'making right-box same height as left-box' is an answer which this question needs.  Almost case (without CSS of height), it would be that right box is smaller than left one.  So, I think there is no need to think of unusually case like its example.  It's  the same as the [case](http://jsfiddle.net/8fuZY/3/) some elements on the right box is larger than 10000px in your code, isn't it?

Comment: @maco, it isn't an unusual case as the OP never stated images would always be taller than content (an extra-wide image would be 'short', regardless of its actual height, as it would be scaled down). Also, yes, my code is limited to 10,000 pixels as written, but the background *always* appears behind the taller column (which is good for accessibility), unlike your solution. Also, 10,000 pixels is more than enough for almost all situations, whereas your solution can break without the text even going off the screen. I've also added an additional solution that doesn't have any of those limitations

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use height (or absolute positionning with top and bottom), the height of the parent must be defined.

You have to assign a height to the parent container:

- Either by explicitely giving it a height
- Or with absolute positioning and specifying top and bottom

Comment: This is a *cleaner* approach

Answer (score 0):

You must establish both heights to 50%